# Is it possible to get the deposit history using Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment

I want to use the Stripe API from the application server that is currently being developed to acquire deposit history data.
If there is no such API, is it possible to detect the deposit with a webhook and save it in the database each time?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "deposit history". The Balance Transaction API will show you how funds are moving through your Stripe account: https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions